# How can I quote (copy + paste) from Google Books?

Tags: copy-paste

Is it possible to copy and paste a part of a book from google books?  I know that they added a feature for copy/pasting from public domains only, but is there a way around this for all books?

I have a lot of quotes that I need, long ones and I would hate to have to type them out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't, this feature is disabled for legal reasons.

but then, who will stop you from making a screen shot and running it through OCR software.

AFAIK, google book downloaders also save their prey as images, so OCR is the only way to get something editable out of it.

Comment: can you suggest a free OCR software?

Comment: here's a freebie, works very well for me: http://www.snapfiles.com/get/topocr.html